# Code igniter Themes' library.

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

I need 3 different templates for my Codeigniter application. I had read about Themes' library. But still I didn't get any idea about how to add a template to Codeignier ..

I got about how to involke template in Controller .

Please help

Comment: From the controller: `$this->load->view('view_name');` - more info at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this template library, is really simple and works well for me.

application/libraries/Template.php

```
<?php
class Template {
    var $template_data = array();
    var $use_template  = '';

    /**
     * Set variable for using in the template
     */
    function set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Set template name
     */
    function set_template($name)
    {
        $this->use_template = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Load view
     */
    function load($view = '' , $view_data = array(), $template = '', $return = FALSE)
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        if (empty($template)) {
            $template = $this->CI->config->item('template_master');
        }

        if (!empty($this->use_template)) {
            $template = $this->use_template;
        }

        $this->set($this->CI->config->item('data_container'), $this->CI->load->view($view, array_merge($view_data, array ('template' => $this->template_data)), true));
        return $this->CI->load->view($this->CI->config->item('template_folder') . '/' . $template, $this->template_data, $return);
    }
}
```

application/config/template.php

```
<?php
$config['template_master']  = 'main';
$config['template_folder']  = 'templates';
$config['data_container']   = 'content';
```

application/views/templates/main.php

```
Header<br />
<?php echo $content; ?></br>
Footer
```

application/controllers/welcome.php

```
<?php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->config('template');
        $this->load->library('template');
        $this->template->load('welcome', array('view' => 'data'));
    }
}
```

I usually put the config/library files on autoload, and you can use anytime $this->template->set_template('other_template'); to use another one :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment and I am gonna try this .. One more doubt ... How to keep different templates in template folder ? Any specific naming conventions or folder structure ?

Comment: Since the way the library loads templates is using the view library of CI, you can put whatever name you want. I'm used to name them like: main.php, admin.php, unauthorized.php, etc.

Comment: OK thanks ... As you said I am gonna save this "Template.php" in Library file create a template named "main.php" also with confg changes and all ...  After that for next template I need to create a new template named "movies.php" and save in templates folder and load that in controller by $this->template->load('movies', array('view' => 'data'));  ...... Will this work or am I need to do again any confg changes ... Thanks

Comment: Oh no, you need to call the movies.php template by $this->template->set_template('movies');, and then load any view inside it with $this->template->load('view_name', $view_data);

Comment: That's right :) config is only needed to define templates folder inside views folder, main template and name of template variable to hold the content.

Comment: Hi, After I tried this I got this following error .. An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: welcome.php    .... Please help

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following setup in a CodeIgniter project:

The different templates along with stylesheets and images are in the following folder:

```
/templates/1/header.php
/templates/1/footer.php
/templates/1/images/*
/templates/1/style/*
/templates/2/header.php
/templates/2/footer.php
/templates/2/images/*
/templates/2/style/*
```

In your Controllers determine which template you want to load and pass the path to that template as a variable ( `templatepath` in this case ) to your View files. Inside the view files you do the following:

```
<?php include($templatepath.'/header.php'); ?>
```

at the top and

```
<?php include($templatepath.'/footer.php'); ?>
```

at the bottom.